# Can't call router outlet component inside another component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to call another component using router outlet but every time it throws an error in below:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'print'
```

I set routing path in my `app-routing.module.ts` like this:

```
{
    path: 'print',
    outlet: 'print',
    component: PrintLayoutComponent  
}
```

And here is `my app.component.html`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="print"></router-outlet>
```

And I am calling `print outlet` like this in another components:

```
this.router.navigate(['/',
  { outlets: {
    'print': ['print']
  }}]);
```

Why this error is happening?
How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: 'print' ,print: 'print'}}]);` or `router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: '/' ,print: 'print'}}]);`